# Kinect exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Tags: c#, kinect

I'm trying to upgrade my Kinect SDK to the new version and having some troubles which I can't figure why.

It breaks as soon as it reaches `kinectSensor.SkeletonFrameReady += this.KinectAllFramesReady;`

```
private KinectSensor kinectSensor;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    kinectSensor.SkeletonFrameReady += this.KinectAllFramesReady;
    kinectSensor.SkeletonStream.Enable(new TransformSmoothParameters()
    {
        Smoothing = 0.5f,
        Correction = 0.5f,
        Prediction = 0.5f,
        JitterRadius = 0.05f,
        MaxDeviationRadius = 0.04f
    });
    kinectSensor.Start();
}
```

Comment: Are you initializing the kinectSensor variable elsewhere?

Comment: Try putting `kinectSensor = KinectSensor.KinectSensors.First();` right after InitializeComponent(). Sort of a hack, you should really detect connect/disconnect a'la the example at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/kinectsdknuiapi/thread/c39bab30-a704-4de1-948d-307afd128dab but should get you started.

Comment: `First();` does not exist. I'll try the detection.

Comment: FIxed it: `kinectSensor = KinectSensor.KinectSensors[0];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Already solved in the comments, but an answer is better for anyone with the same problem;

The problem with the code is that it declares the kinectSensor variable, but never sets it to anything. There's a pretty good code example at [MSDN Social](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/kinectsdknuiapi/thread/c39bab30-a704-4de1-948d-307afd128dab) on how to do detection of connected/disconnected devices, but a very simple version just to get started playing around is to **just use the first entry in the static `KinectSensor.KinectSensors` collection** which will be your first connected sensor.